# Near-future series, maybe four novels

Tags: story-identification, novel, underground-civilization

The people live in several underground facilities.
The story is about a young woman training to patrol the surface.
She falls for her trainer who has a brother he left on the surface
There is something killing off the people underground. A disease? That leadership is keeping secret

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/53651416-the-immortal-oath?

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/125162502

Answer (score 1):

Just possibly the Aestus series by S. Z. Attwell.

The first book is [The City](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/55039899).

[image]

> When Jossey was ten, the creatures of the aboveground took her brother and left her for dead, with horrible scars. Now, years later, she’s a successful solar engineer, working to keep her underground city’s power running, but she’s never really recovered. After she saves dozens of people during a second attack, she is offered a top-secret assignment as a field Engineer with Patrol, but fear prevents her from taking it…until Patrol finds bones near where her brother disappeared.
>
> She signs on and finds herself catapulted into a world that is far more dangerous, and requires far more of her, than she ever imagined. The creatures and the burning heat aboveground are not the only threats facing the City, and what she learns during her assignment could cost her her life: one of the greatest threats to the City may in fact lie within. With thousands of lives at stake, can she act in time?

It does seem to match your description in a lot of ways, but there are only two books in the series not four.

Comment: Thank you, but that is not the novels I am looking for. The herione is young and attractive. It is about her training to patrol the surface - a very dangerous task because of the people left up there.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe Hugh Howey`s Silo Universe?
https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?50066

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi Юрий, you may want to take the [tour]. I've only read the first book of Silo, but at least in Wool no one trains to patrol the surface